# A differential form with integration $1$ has to be integral?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface. If $\Omega\in H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$, s.t. $\int_X\Omega=1$, then why is $\Omega$ integral?

A $d$-closed differential form $\phi$ on $X$ is said to be integral if its cohomology class in the de Rham group, $[\phi]\in H^*(X,\mathbb{C})$, is in the image of the natural mapping:
$H^*(X,\mathbb{Z})\to H^*(X,\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you give a (natural) isomorphism $H^2(X,\Bbb C)\cong\Bbb C$? You evaluate on the fundamental class $[X]\in H_2(X,\Bbb Z)$, which means—in the deRham picture—that you integrate over $X$. The integral cohomology $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$ then corresponds to $\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb C$: A cohomology class gives you an integer for the integral if and only if it comes from an element of $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Can you tell me the reference for the claim of "if and only if"?

Comment: Remember that $H^2(X,\Bbb Z) \cong \text{Hom}(H_2(X,\Bbb Z),\Bbb Z)$. The (oriented) generator $\phi$ corresponds to evaluation on the generator of $H_2(X,\Bbb Z)$, which is the fundamental class. If $\int_X\omega = c\in\Bbb C$, then $[\omega] = c\phi$.

Comment: Is that statement that the integral of a form is integer iff it's the form is integral true for any form or just for top form?

Comment: And why is $\int_X\phi=1$?

Comment: We're talking about only the top-degree forms/classes here. Only there do you have a canonical generator for the integral homology. To answer your last question, what does it mean to have a generator for $\text{Hom}(\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z$?

Comment: But, I think the generator, say $\omega$, means, for the fundamental class $\alpha$, $\int_\alpha\omega=1$, which is different from $\int_X\omega=1$

Comment: No, the homology class represented by the compact manifold $X$ (as, here, a $2$-cycle) *is* the fundamental class.